# Password field in AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-edittext

I have created a alert dialog with edit text. How to set the property of the edittext as password?

Here is the code...

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText input = new EditText(this);

input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

alert.setView(input);    //edit text added to alert
alert.setTitle("Password Required");   //title setted
```

Comment: input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
| InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

Answer (score 8):

```
input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```